# Re-Assign Text Through Text Content (Using A Unicode Symbol)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coding a Tic Tac Toe Program In Which I Have To Switch Between Two Player Turns (Player #1 | Player #2). When displaying the turns I use the arrow unicode symbol: `&#8594`. Whenever I change the text content of this turn display I can't add back the unicode symbol.

```
const turnDisplay = document.querySelector('#turnDisplay');

turnDisplay.textContent = '(Player #2 &#8594 Turn)'
```

[Original Tic Tac Toe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwQkp.png)

[Tic Tac Toe After Turn Display Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TzdD.png)

How do I reassign a unicode variable through text content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the innerHTML property like this -

```js
const turnDisplay = document.querySelector('#turnDisplay');

turnDisplay.innerHTML = 'Player #2 &#8594 Turn';
```

```html
<p id="turnDisplay"></p>
```

Comment: When someone answers your question, you can accept the answer that worked for you to help other people with the same problem. Here is a link that you may find helpful [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

`turnDisplay.textContent = '(Player #2 &#8594 Turn)'` //here &#8594 is a html rightarrow unicode . to get that you have to use dollar($) symbol and the total strings should be enclosed in a tilde(`) symbol instead of apostrophe(')

```
turnDisplay.textContent = `(Player #2 ${&#8594} Turn)`
```

Comment: Thank you both so much! Thx is helps a ton 